# Passing/returning callback function result

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, javascript

I think I am running into a callback issue as returning the result is saying undefined (despite being shown correctly in the console log).

```
web3.eth.getBlockNumber(function(error, result){
    if(!error)
    {
        console.log(result)
        return result
    }
    else
    {
        console.error(error);
        alert(error)
    }
})
```

I'm unable to pass the callback result to another function/variable currently. Please assist. Thanks.

Comment: what problem/error are you having? you appear to be `return`ing the result and not passing it anywhere

Comment: try alert(result) to see if it pops up correctly

Comment: i'm getting undefined in the console and if i alert it.

Comment: have you included web3.js or MetaMask-injected? `<script src="https://unpkg.com/web3@1.0.0-beta.27/src/index.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

This is a common point of confusion for new JavaScript developers. If you want to pass `result` to something else, you need to call another function. E.g.:

```
web3.eth.getBlockNumber(function (error, result) {
  otherFunction(result);
});

function otherFunction(result) {
  console.log("In otherFunction with: " + result);
}
```

Currently, you're just `return`ing `result`, which just means it gets returned to the caller of your callback, which is `web3.eth.getBlockNumber` (and it isn't expecting a return value from the callback at all, so it ignores it).

Comment: ok, but what's the solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. My answer includes working code.